# How to apply table style, also set header value as True to table created in Excel using Python?

Tags: python

My code below works to add a dataframe into Excel and create a table, but I get a syntax error when I try to apply style.

```
import pandas
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.worksheet.table import Table
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

book = load_workbook('QualityReview Business-Template.xlsx')
writer = pandas.ExcelWriter('QualityReview Business-Template.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') 
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
busi_issue_date.to_excel(writer, "IssueData")
tab = openpyxl.worksheet.table.Table(displayName="busi_issue_date", ref=f'A1:{openpyxl.utils.get_column_letter(busi_issue_date.shape[1])}{len(busi_issue_date)+1,'style': 'Table Style Medium 10'}')

worksheet = book["IssueData"]
worksheet.add_table(tab)
writer.save()
```

I get this error:

> tab = openpyxl.worksheet.table.Table(displayName="busi_issue_date", ref=f'A1:{openpyxl.utils.get_column_letter(busi_issue_date.shape[1])}{len(busi_issue_date)+1,'style': 'Table Style Medium 10'}')
> ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

I guess that this is the correct answer

```
tab = Table(displayName="busi_issue_date", ref=f'A1:{openpyxl.utils.get_column_letter(busi_issue_date.shape[1])}{len(busi_issue_date)+1}', style ='Table Style Medium 10')
```

However I am not sure if style is right. Maybe try to change it with tableStyleInfo.